# Give edit permissions for public document in skydrive?

Tags: windows-live, onedrive

I have a document in my "Public" folder in Windows Live Skydrive. Everyone can see it, but I'm trying to give collaborator write-access. I can't figure out how to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are some folders, like "Public" and "My Documents", that you can change the settings of. But you can create new folders, and invite people to edit the documents inside them.